# Google API: Moving from Simple API Key to OAuth

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

From the Android API console I just created an OAuth API access *client id*. I am currently using a **Simple API** browser key for use with GCM / YouTube API. How do I switch from a simple api browser key to using OAuth (which doesn't appear to have a key) ?

FYI the simple API key is used on the server to process "push notifications". Since OAuth doesn't appear to have a "key" how do I go about making this switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I misunderstood the idea of OAuth for google applications. From what I understand you can let a user log into google via your app which gives them unlimited access to api features. I didn't wanted users to log in via google so I just went back to the old way of using a browser key via the simple api.